# How to change scss variable value base on user extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, sass, sencha-touch, extjs6

I want to change the theme color of extjs app based on the color provide by the user at run time.
Is it possible to override scss varible and create css file again so that i can apply my custom style to whole app

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to change SCSS and compile it to CSS at runtime :)

Comment: basically you can do it, but only with server side work, i guess that wasn't his will.